# Ad pauses when tapped on the full screen expander icon during Ad playback

Tags: ios, safari, html5-video, kaltura

Ad get paused when clicked on full screen expander icon during Ad playback.

You can also follow the steps for clear understanding the issue:

1. Launch Voot.com URL in Safari browser.
2. Play any content.
3. During Ad playback tap on full screen minimizer.
4. Again during Ad playback tap on full screen expander.

Ad should not get paused on tapping on fullscreen expander.

It will also fine if anyone can help in hiding control bar of kaltura player while playing the Ad.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is fine with the default settings, but perhaps you (or I) have something set that I'm not sure of.
You can take a look at settings here:  http://player.kaltura.com/docs/api

For controls during ad playback, set this true:
http://player.kaltura.com/docs/api#enableControlsDuringAd

Also, look at `EmbedPlayer.NativeControls` - but I found if you set that to false while `enableControlsDuringAd` is true, the settings may interfere? I'm not 100% sure if that is true - it could be something else I was doing - but you will see it if it does.